# How can I query the Exchange Global Addresslist with Applescript or Perl?

Tags: perl, applescript, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I want to extract some addresses from Exchange's Global Address list but have absolutely no clue where to start.

I'm using a Mac and so the idea was to use applescript, but I do not understand how to even connect to the GAL.

I also could not find any examples yet. Does someone here know of some examples how to work with Exchange's global address list using Applescript? Or maybe in Bash or Perl?

Comment: Se also Perl module [EWS::Client](https://metacpan.org/pod/EWS::Client) and the Python [`exchangelib`](https://pypi.org/project/exchangelib/) module.

Comment: Try to see for information [here](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=313813) and [here](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1127110) it would be good start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue I had was finding the LDAP servers for my case.

Finally I found information how to do this, and it's quite simple:

```
dig -t SRV +short _ldap._tcp.my.do.main
```

When I have the server name (or names) it's simply a matter of authenticating and browsing around to find the infos required.

```
    ldapsearch -h "$LDAP_SERVER" -p "$LDAP_PORT" -b "$USER_BASEDN" -D "$LDAP_USER" -w "$PASSWD" "(&(QUERY))"
```

Answer (score 2):

For what version of Exchange ? EWS doesn't provide any really good methods of doing this apart from FindPeople which requires you have the GUID of the Global Address list. Generally its a better idea to use LDAP on a Mac look at ldapsearch see https://its-a-feature.github.io/posts/2018/01/Active-Directory-Discovery-with-a-Mac/ and then use a query like

```
(& (mailnickname=*)(objectClass=user))
```

If you using Office365 then use the Graph API which give you direct access to the underlying directory.